# Run testcases that belong to multiple categories in JUNIT

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit5

I have created 2 categories IND.class and MANUAL.class
and have added test methods to them as well.

Is it possible to run the common testcases in the categories.

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't, but since you can assign two different categories to a test or to a class of tests you could add a third category such `Common.class` and annotate the common tests with `@Category({IND.class, Common.class})` or `@Category({MANUAL.class, Common.class})`